# Failed to get avatar using OData $expand in Microsoft Graph

Tags: json, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am trying to get avatar using OData `$expand` in Microsoft Graph.

When I run

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$expand=photo
```

in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#), I got this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "RequestBroker-ParseUri",
        "message": "Could not find a property named 'businessPhones' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.User'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "cf7937be-169f-41a1-80fb-cf184f0b5a72",
            "date": "2017-07-26T22:48:30"
        }
    }
}
```

Am I using it correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope - this is not possible.  If you are trying to get both the profile **and** the photo at the same time, please try using a `$batch` operation.  See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching

Hope this helps,

Comment: If `$expand` is not working, does that mean Microsoft Graph API is not compatible with OData, or only this case? Thanks

Comment: `$expand` is supported by Microsoft Graph for most scenarios (but probably not all) - but is definitely not supported in this case when expanding to photo. However JSON batching should give you a relatively similar alternative.  Also is there a reason that OData compliance is important for your scenario?

Comment: Thanks! No, just think it would be nature to get a profile with avatar info.